# How do I parse/split the second specific character from the right to left?

Tags: vb6

I have strings like this:

sometexthere_moretext_moretext_12512512521_251125512125

or:

sometexthere_moretext_12512512521_251125512125

I need in any of this cases two case scenarios to parse like this:

var1 = sometexthere_moretext_moretext_
var2 = 12512512521_251125512125

and

var1 = sometexthere_moretext_
var2 = 12512512521_251125512125

So I'm trying to find how to parse/split the second "_" from right to left. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim variable As String
variable = sometexthere_moretext_moretext_12512512521_251125512125

Dim StringArray() As String
StringArray() = Split(variable, "_")


For i = 0 To UBound(StringArray)
    MsgBox Trim$(StringArray(i))
Next
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close, `UBound(StringArray)` will return 4 in this example, so you want to start from index 3:

```
Dim variable As String
variable = "sometexthere_moretext_moretext_12512512521_251125512125"

Dim StringArray() As String
StringArray() = Split(variable, "_")

Dim var1 As String
Dim var2 As String

' Build var1
var1 = ""
For i = 0 To (UBound(StringArray) - 2)
    If var1 <> "" Then var1 = var1 & "_"
    var1 = var1 & Trim$(StringArray(i))
Next

' Build var2
var2 = ""
For i = (UBound(StringArray) - 1) To UBound(StringArray)
    If var2 <> "" Then var2 = var2 & "_"
    var2 = var2 & Trim$(StringArray(i))
Next

MsgBox "var1: " & var1 & vbCrLf & "var2: " & var2
```

With this code, no matter how many fields are before the numbers, you will only get the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Another way, using instrRev :

```
Dim leftPart as string, rightPart as String, var1 as string
var1 = "sometexthere_moretext_moretext_12512512521_251125512125"
If UBound(Split(var1, "_")) >= 2 Then 'Assuming you have at least 2 "_" in var1
    leftPart = Left(var1, InstrRev(Left(var1, instrRev(var1, "_") - 1), "_") - 1)
    rightPart = Mid(var1, InstrRev(Left(var1, instrRev(var1, "_") - 1), "_") + 1)
Endif
```